# plotting error message using mglearn

Tags: python, matplotlib

From page 32 in Mũller/Guido "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python"

```
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],y)
```

results in message:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mglearn-0.1.6- py3.5.egg/mglearn/plot_helpers.py", line 80, in discrete_scatter
>    for i, (yy, cycle) in enumerate(zip(unique_y, current_cycler())):
>    TypeError: `Cycler` object is not callable

I am running 
Python 3.5, Linux Mint 18.3, & mglearn 0.1.6 installed from mglearn-0.1.6.tar.gz

This works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(X[:,0],'ro', color='red')
plt.plot(X[:,1],'ro',color='blue')
```

but what I got originally (shown above and in accordance with the book) seems like a bug.
Some module that must be installed maybe?

Comment: Yes, there seem to be a bug somewhere.

Comment: I have solved it. A more recent version of Cycler than the one I had did the trick.